# Does PHP have an equivalent to ColdFusion's QueryNew?

Tags: php, coldfusion

I'm migrating from ColdFusion to PHP and have an application that uses ColdFusion's QueryNew function to dynamically build what is to me basically an in-memory database table that I can then run full SQL queries against to search, group, sort, etc.

I'm wondering what the technique would be to do this same thing in PHP or one of its frameworks. I'm sure I could just build it as an array or JSON, but then I'm not as familiar in searching, grouping, and sorting an object like that as I am doing it with SQL.

Comment: maybe you can try creating an temporary table in MySQL ?

Comment: A little off topic, but wouldn't it just be easier to keep using CFML?

Comment: They're created on every page view per user, so I'm assuming temporary tables would have a performance hit for something like that, yeah? It would be a bit difficult to maintain only this small piece of CFML in a new environment. Perhaps I just need to work on better models.